# How to create custom login page in windows xp

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, windows-server-2008

I would like to create **custom login page** in windows server machine using c#.When i login to the server remotely which should have to take the user name and password as the current login..
First of all i would like to know what is the procedure to change the login page for windows.

Comment: What you want is not likely to be possible when your trying log into the server remotely.  You would either have to always replace it or never replace it.

Comment: This is not the sort of thing that you normally do just because you would 'like to'. I would view this similar to attempting to write your own device driver, in that it is difficult to do, difficult to debug and potentially disastrous if you get it wrong. So you only go down this path if you really **need** to do it. And if you do need to do this, you don't do use C# (just like you would not write a device driver in C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly want to achieve... but this seems a good starting point
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Although I'd be pretty surprised if it was possible to replace the GINA using managed code

Comment: Note, that replacements GINA will work in Windows-XP, but not in Windows Server 2008 or Vista or Windows 7 which uses a completely different method (something called credential provider model).

Answer (score 0):

For windows XP you can use this:
http://www.stardock.com/products/logonstudio/

For windows 7 you can use this:
http://tweaks.com/windows/39468/customizing-logon-screen-background-in-windows-7/

Both can be done manually also (without a special program). But if you want to do this, then you need to be at least advanced enough to find the manual from google. Else you might break your Win installation. :(